# Systemd: unable to mask service using kernel parameters

Tags: arch-linux, systemd

I'm trying to create GRUB menu options that will allow to skip launching GDM and, eventually, launch LightDM instead of GDM (so options for text-mode booting isn't a solution). I have added **systemd.mask=gdm.service** to kernel command line, like in [this link](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/kernel-command-line.html), but GDM starts anyway.

Tried **systemd.mask=gdm**, it didn't work either.

Menu option is (formatted for readability):

```
linux   /vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/mapper/vol-name rw
cryptdevice=/dev/sda5:root 
root=/dev/group/vol
resume=/dev/mapper/swap-vol-name quiet 
nvidia-drm.modeset=1
module_blacklist=nvidia
systemd.mask=gdm.service
```

Systemd is version 241 and systemd-debug-generator, which is responsible for parsing the option, is present in /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators.

Distro is Arch Linux.

Comment: So, why do you have to do this using kernel parameters?

Comment: Because it seems most simple (not needed to create different runlevel) and obvious way to boot without some service launched. Also I disabled gdm once several years ago using similar method (kernel parameter) so I know systemd parses kernel command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using some help from [Arch Linux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=244642), it turned out the name of service to be masked is "display-manager.service", so proper parameter for masking is **systemd.mask=display-manager.service**